# Exception has occurred: IndexError list index out of range

Tags: python, indexing, multiprocessing, range, pool

I have a problem with this code: specifically it returns the error Exception has occurred: IndexError list index out of range even if the whole process is iterated by for loops and therefore it is impossible for the process to go out of the index .
The program in question starts a pool of threads which iterates the chunks list so that operations are performed on the records in that list.
I noticed that the error only comes up when the process moves to the last element of the chunks list.
The error occurs in the command "udated_records = p.imap(data_scraping, chunks)"

```
    with Pool(4) as p:
        # Calcola la lunghezza di ogni suddivisione (La lista deve essere divisa per il numero esatto di sottoprocessi)
        chunk_size = len(result) // 6
        # Calcola il reso della suddivisione (Verrà poi attribuito all'ultima esecuzione)
        chunk_rest = len(result) % 6

        # Dividi la lista in 4 parti (= al numero di sottoprocessi)
        chunks = [result[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(result) - (len(result) % 6), chunk_size)]
        # Se è presente del resto viene assegnato all'ultima sottolista
        if(chunk_rest>0):
            # Assegna la parte rimanente all'ultima suddivisione (assegna il resto all'ultima sottolista)
            chunks[-1].extend(result[-chunk_rest:])
        print('chunks', chunks)
        print('chunk1', chunks[0])
        print('chunk2', chunks[1])
        print('chunk3', chunks[2])
        print('chunk4', chunks[3])
        print('chunk5', chunks[4])
        print('chunk6', chunks[5])

        udated_records = p.imap(data_scraping, chunks)
        array = [chunk for chunk in  udated_records]
```

I've tried verifying the integrity of the chunks list and chunk sublists and they seem to have no problems. I deleted some superfluous libraries in the program but it doesn't seem to have solved

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there the whole stacktrace?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).